# Get value from input while on the same page

Tags: php, html

So I have a page with a hidden input field that is populated from a process page. I want to make a php variable that has the value of whatever is the value of the input box. How can I do this?

### EDIT

added code.  So basically I need a variable ($curActiveJobNames) that has the value of whatever is in the curJobName input field.

Front Page

```
<p><input id="curJobName" value=""></input></p>

                <p > 
                    <?  if ($curActiveJobName) {
                            $gearSrc = 'fa fa-gear fa-spin';
                            $activeOperations = 1;
                        } else {
                            $gearSrc = 'fa fa-gear';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <i class="<?=$gearSrc; ?>"></i>
                    <?if ($curActiveJobName) {
                        if($curActiveJobName == 'deployVApp') {
                            print $curActiveJobName . " - " . $vApp->get('status');
                        } else {
                            print $curActiveJobName;
                        }
                    } elseif ($vApp->get('status') == 'PR') {
                        print $languageDB->berkGet("content_provisioning");
                    } elseif ($vApp->get('status') == 'FA') {
                        print $languageDB->berkGet("content_failed_to_create");
                    } elseif ($vApp->get('status') == 'IN') {
                        print $languageDB->berkGet("content_stopped");
                    } else {
                        print $languageDB->berkGet("content_none");
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
```

included file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeJob = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/processJobStatus.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { action: 'jobStatus' },
            async: true,
            success: function(returnParameters) {
                count = returnParameters.count;
                status = returnParameters.status;

                if(count > 0) {
                    activeJob = true;
                    name = returnParameters.name;
                    status = returnParameters.status;
                    $('#clientJobList').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#jobName').html(name);
                    document.getElementById("curJobName").value = name;
                    $('#jobStatus').html(status);
                } else {
                    if (activeJob === true) {
                        activeJob = false;
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                    $('#clientJobList').css('display', 'none');
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you add some code we could help you based on your specific problem. I am guessing you are looking for something like posting a form. If that is the case there would be numerous solutions on google, here is one: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html